# What parameters are available for Facebook API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I know that there is available `&limit` parameter for `/feed` endpoint. However, on it's documentation page, it is nowhere mentioned that there exists `limit` parameter:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.0/page/feed

How i should have known that? Where I can see what other parameters are available for query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before hitting the reference, you should check out the general docs:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/

It´s like a "getting started" article, useful for every developer.